# MySQL Calculate count, sum and percentage with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, sum

I have a payments table with the following fields:

- id (int)
- status (successful, failed, refunded)
- amount (int)
- pdate (Y-m-d format)

I need to write a query to get, for each day how many payments were successful, how many failed and how many were refunded, with the percentage for that day. My current query is this:

```
select pdate, status, count(*) as total, sum(amount) as total_amount
from payments
group by pdate, status
```

The query successfully returns how many payments were processed on each day and the status:

```
pdate        status       total   total_amount
2019-04-01,  successful,     10,           100
2019-04-01,  failed,          5,            50
2019-04-01,  refunded,        5,            50
2019-04-02,  successful,     12,           120
2019-04-02,  failed,          5,            50
2019-04-02,  refunded,        3,            30
```

But I don't know how to make it calculate the percentage for each payment for each day. For example, for `2019-04-01` there were `20` payments so, the percentage of `successful` payments = `50%`, `failed` = `25%` and `refunded` = `25%`.

How can I make it return this:

```
pdate        status       total   total_amount    percentage
2019-04-01,  successful,     10,           100,          50%        
2019-04-01,  failed,          5,            50,          25%
2019-04-01,  refunded,        5,            50,          25%
2019-04-02,  successful,     12,           120,        58.3%
2019-04-02,  failed,          5,            50,        16.6%
2019-04-02,  refunded,        3,            30,          25%
```

As you can see, the percentage is calculated based on the total number of payments for each day.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *the percentage is calculated based on the total number of payments for each day* can you explain 58.3%?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery within your select statement to accomplish this. Refer down below:

```
select 
    p1.pdate, 
    p1.status, 
    count(*)  as total, 
    sum(p1.amount) as total_amount, 
    concat(round(( count(*)/
        (select count(*) from payments p2 where p2.pdate = p1.pdate group by pdate ) 
    * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage 
from 
    payments p1 
group by pdate, status;
```

This will get you what you are looking for. Check out this running example:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e6a6CJb3pqLzcRz18SGeZ2/1

Comment: If this solves your problem, may you kindly accept this as the answer? Thank you!